# Pass additional class to angular 6 material component

Tags: angular

So I may be using Angular the wrong way here, but what I'm trying to do is instantiate a component and add another class to it. So for instance, a material button looks like this:

`<button mat-button color="primary">{{text}}</button>`

And if I call it somewhere with

`<app-material-button text="Something"></app-material-button>`

it works fine. However, when I attempt to the same thing with an additional class, it'll add it, but lose all the classes it needs to look correct.

```
// Component template
    <button mat-button color="primary" class={{addon}}>{{text}}</button>
// Instance 
    <app-material-button text="Something" addon="smaller-button"></app-material-button>
```

My question is basically how can I append a class to a component alongside literally whatever else classes it wants to append to itself on init?

I know I may be using Angular like React here, but it's a simple enough thing to do!

Comment: Haven't worked with material but in Angular to set classess use ngClass directive.
Something like  [ngClass] = "{addon : true}"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `addon` is an `Input decorator` ... Use `[addon]="'smaller-button'"` to send a value and use `[ngClass]` directive in the child component

```
<button mat-button color="primary" [ngClass]="{addon: true}">{{text}}</button>
<app-material-button text="Something" [addon]="'smaller-button'"></app-material-button>
```

Comment: Yeah, it is, so if it's a `string` decorator, or an object, I'll get: `ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"` in the child element, as well as `ng-reflect-addon="smaller-button"` in the parrent. But nowhere is the class added to additional classes

Comment: do you mean that you want append this class?

Comment: Yeah, since it's material, it'll add a bunch of its' own classes. I just want to add 1 more when I need it basically. So the `<button mat-button>Hi</button>` will be instantiated as `<button _ngcontent-c2="" class="mat-button mat-button-primary" color="primary" mat-button="" ng-reflect-color="primary">Hi</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class when the template expression evaluates to truthy. It removes the class when the expression is falsy.

```
<div class="special" [class.special]="!isSpecial">This one is not so special</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I'm not sure I understand. So if I add that to the template, would I call it with `<div special>` and then it'll apply an additional class?

Comment: Suppose you have 3 classes A1,A2,A3. A1 and A2 should always be present. Class A3 should be present based on a Boolean variable isSpecial.

So your code will be 
<div class="A1 A2" [class.A3] ="isSpecial">

Comment: Oh that makes sense, let me give it a go and get back to you!